# Reinsert position of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

On some javascript condition, How to remove mynavbar and insert into main_table div

```
<div id="mynavbar" > <div>Some content</div>  </div>

<div id="main_table"> </div>

<script>
if(condtion == 0)
{
    How to remove mynavbar and insert into main_table div

}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `.appendTo()`.

```
$('#mynavbar').appendTo('#main_table');
```

Reference: [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: thats what i meant to write! messed the last bit up royally

Comment: I should use .remove() right and then use append.What is the difference between append() and appendto()

Comment: @Rajeev: no, you don't need to call `.remove()`. `append()` and `.appendTo()` will transfer the node within the DOM for you. Difference between this two is that `.appendTo()` operates on the node of invocation, so you can chain further calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condtion == 0)
{
    $("#mynavbar").appendTo("#main_table");

}
```